# $(this).attr("id"); returns undefined

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table with nav elements that I want to highlight when they are active.  I have code to do this.  The problem with the code is that I cannot seem to capture the id of the clicked item.  It returns undefined.  Please show me the error of my ways.  I'm really a backend developer with just a little bit of jquery/javascript knowledge.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.link-active-td').removeClass('link-active-td');
    $('.link-active-text').removeClass('link-active-text');
    var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(linkid)
    $("#" + linkid).children().addClass('link-active-td');
    $("#" + linkid).parent().addClass('link-active-text');
  });
});
```

```css
.link-active-td,
.link-active-text {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
      <a class="a-nav" id="1td" href="#">
        <div>
          First Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td id="2">
      <a class="a-nav" id="2td" href="#">
        <div>
          Second Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td id="3">
      <a class="a-nav" id="3td" href="#">
        <div>
          Second Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Strange, it seems work: https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/yLOMGjm?editors=1111

Comment: `var linkid = $(this).attr("id"); $("#" + linkid)...` would select `this` so why don't you use `this` directly?

Comment: Why do you add `.link-active-td` to the `<div>` and `.link-active-text` to the `<td>`?

Comment: Error in 2nd line of code `$(‘a’).click(function()` there should be different symbols like `$('a').click(function()`

Comment: Those are some strange quotes: `$(‘a’)`

Comment: I've taken the liberty of converting to a snippet (with console.log and fixed quotes as that didn't appear to be relevant to the question (as wouldn't give `undefined` if it stopped the event handler from working))

Comment: @freedomn-m I think that You've actually resolved the code by fixing the quotes problem and updated code-snippet seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved not so sure I changed anything as @Zecka also confirmed it working before this.   If it was the quote issue (the only actual change) then OP would not be getting an event to get `undefined`.  Suggesting vote close as typo or needs clarity as no response from OP regarding the quotes.

Comment: @freedomn-m but Zecka has also fixed quotation error, see his codepen. I agree with that return of 'undefined' is strange, OP should clarify what is the actual output/error message.

Comment: @user2547177 what happens if you use `$("a").click..` instead of `$(‘a’).click`?

Answer (score -1):

Tried capturing the id, have used the same code as that of yours. I tried consoling the o/p using console.log($(this).attr("id"))?
Please find my chunk of code where i tried capturing the id value. and it returns correct id. Can you please check the quotes used for 'a' in the code

`````
                $('a').click(function() {
                    $('.link-active-td').removeClass('link-active-td');
                    $('.link-active-text').removeClass('link-active-text');
                    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                    var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
                    $("#" + linkid).children().addClass('link-active-td');
                    $("#" + linkid).parent().addClass('link-active-text');
                });
            });````
`````

Comment: _"...where i tried capturing the id value"_ - You've only modified the `console.log()` call o.O

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - as you'll see from the existing comments, "works for me" isn't generally considered an answer - we need to work with OP (if they return...) to find out why they think their code doesn't work for them (when it clearly does work).  You need a little more rep to ask questions, which you can get by providing answers

Comment: Okay so I verified some things
I put an alert in and it is returning the correct class
I also verified in the console that if linkid is correct the code works. 
So I don't understand what's going wrong.  
Debugging help would be great.  I'm not sure what approach to take.

Comment: Thanks - @freedomn-m would take care of that next time, to ask question  and provide debugging help.